# Fish: Compiler apparently not waiting the execution of previous command

Tags: function, fish

Using Fish functions when I run "rmccw *"
the *.out files are excluded, as expected, but the compiler doesn't run and I get this error:

```
input file 'a.out' is the same as output file
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I run the same command a second time (there's no .out files) the compiler runs normally. A a.out file is created.

```
function rmouts
        set outs *.out
        if count $outs >/dev/null
                rm -f *.out
        end
end

function ccw
        cc $argv -Wall -Wextra -Werror
end

function rmccw
        rmouts
        ccw $argv
end
```

Instead of using rmccw if I run "rmouts && ccw *" I get no errors.
I already tried to add a "wait $last_pid" after rmouts, but it didn't work either.

Instead of using rmccw if I run "rmouts && ccw *" I get no errors.
I already tried to add a "wait $last_pid" after rmouts, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `rmccw *`, fish expands `*` **before** invoking the function. You *are* passing `.out` files to `ccw`.

Here's a command to filter out `.out` files from `$argv`:

```
set i 1
while test $i -le (count $argv)
    if string match -q '*.out' $argv[$i]
        set -e argv[$i]
    else
        set i (math $i + 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: It's probably easier to make a new variable - `set -l files; for f in $argv; string match -q '*.out' $f; or set -a files $f; end`